# Show that the set of Endormorphism of a given graph is equal to the set of Automorphism.

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

Let $A$ be the $10 \times 10 = [a_{ij}]$, where $a_{ij} = (i, j)$. Let $G$ be a graph whose vertex set is the eateries of the matrix $A$ and the two distinct vertex $(i, j)$ and $(k, l)$ are adjacent if 
$$k \neq j \;  \text{and} \; l \neq i.$$

I have found lots of graph theoretic  properties of this  graph such that neighbourhood of every vertex, chromatic number clique number, independence number etc.

> > I want to prove that End$(G) = $Aut$(G)$.

I guess that End$(G) = $Aut$(G)$. We know that End$(G) \subseteq$S-End$(G) \subseteq$ Aut$(G)$, where S-End$(G)$ is the set of strong endomorphisn on a graph $G$. A endomorphism is said to be strong endomorphism if $f(x)$ is adjacent to $f(y)$ implies $x$ is adjacent to $y$. I found that S-End$(G) = $Aut$(G)$.  We need to show that End$(G) = $S-End$(G)$.

I have also tried to prove my result by using the  concept of core. A graph $G$ is said to be a core if  and only if Aut$G$ = End$(G)$. If $H$ is a  proper subgraph of $G$, then a homomorphism $f : G \rightarrow H$ is called retraction if $f(h) = h \; \forall h \in H$ and $H$ is called retract. We know that a graph is a core if and only it admits no retract.

Comment: Isn't $(i,j)\mapsto (i,i)$ a weak endomorphism?

Comment: This is not an endomorhism. Because $(1, 2)$  is adjacent with $(1, 3)$ but $f(1, 2) = (1, 1) = f(1, 3)$.